# Java:ObjectInputStream returns same Object

Tags: java, sockets, object, inputstream, objectinputstream

I am programming java network using sockets and exchanging data between the remote programs using a Simple objects.

In present case I have an `ObjectInputStream` constructed using :

```
new ObjectInputStream(Socket.getInputStream())
```

So I am using `writeObject` method to write a Object that contains some String fields.

However the receiver when calls `readObject` it always returns the same object.

To check this I set one of the string fields to store current time. While writing the object its always different time for each object. but received object all show same single time in the string field.

Clearly speaking every object returned after each call to `ObjectInputStream.ReadObject` is a exact clone of other

why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing objectInputStream.reset();